# NHibernate Parent Child Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, parent, relationship

I have a parent/child database relationship between the table ACCOUNT and the table USER. Currently I have mapped a bi-directional Fluent mappings like this:

```
public class Account {
  public virtual IList<User> ListUsers { get; private set; }

  public virtual void AddUser(User user)
  {
    user.Account = this;
    ListUsers.Add(user);
  }
}

MAPPING: HasMany(x => x.ListUsers).Table("UserInfo").KeyColumn("Id_Account").Inverse().Cascade.All().AsList();

public class User {
  public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; } 
}

MAPPING: References(x => x.Account).Column("Id_Account");
```

In practice I cannot foresee that I will ever want to reference the Account entity from the User entity. Likewise I cannot foresee my wanting to load all of the User entities from the parent Accounts entity. I am fairly new to NHibernate and was wondering is the above method still the best way to go performance wise? Is a bi-directional relationship preferred and should I look to referencing the Id only? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. bi-directional references *is* the correct approach, in my opinion. If you use lazy-loading on the `Account` property, then it would only load the account's id anyway.
2. you specified that the `ListUsers` property is `inverse=true`, meaning the `User` entity is responsible for saving the reference. Therefore, I believe (if I remember correctly) that the line `ListUsers.Add(user);` is not necessary, since the association will be created by the `User` entity.
   So this means that you don't have to load the entire `ListUsers` collection from the db when you add a user.